# firewall masquerade configuration not working

Tags: linux, networking, nat, masquerade

I'm using RHEL 8 and am trying to set-up NAT/MASQUERADE using firewall-cmd. So far I have all the network interfaces and services in the public zone. eno8303 is the internal nic and eno8403 is the external nic. This is my procedure but I can't get it to work:-

`sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eno8303 -j MASQUERADE sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -A FORWARD -i eno8403 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

edit /etc/sysctl.conf to include the setting
`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

And then
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf

Expected to be able to use the server as an internal gateway but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your configuration, you should use the external NIC `eno8403` as the output interface instead of the internal one.

here is how to fix that: first set up the NAT `sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eno8403 -j MASQUERADE`then set up the forward rules

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -A FORWARD -i eno8303 -o eno8403 -j ACCEPT
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --passthrough ipv4 -A FORWARD -i eno8403 -o eno8303 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

then reload `sudo firewall-cmd --reload` then go to `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

then you apply, and it should work `sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`